# When writing a paper, do I have to describe what $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation, article-writing

Or can I expect the reader to know that that denotes the set of complex numbers and natural numbers, respectively?

Or must I have "...where $\mathbb{C}$ denotes the field of complex numbers..."?

Comment: You should expect them to know basic notations unless your intended audiences aren't math students or researchers.

Comment: The only thing you might need to specify is whether or not $0 \in \mathbb N$, if it matters.

Comment: It's easy and potentially helpful to provide a quick definition, especially in the case of the natural numbers.

Comment: There's a lot of "standard notation" out there. If notation is non-standard, then you are expected to declare what something means within the paper. I expect that any mathematical audience will know what $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb N$ are, though you would be expected to declare what you mean in context; $\Bbb C$ as a set or a field for instance.

Comment: If you're writing a paper for a mathematically mature audience (e.g., a professional journal), then absolutely not. If it matters whether $0\in \mathbb{N}$, then just write something like, "For any blah blah blah $x$ in $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, \dots\}$" in the first usage, then use $\mathbb{N}$ without any explanation afterward. The usage of $\mathbb{C}$, however, is ubiquitous and elementary.

Comment: It depends on the level of the paper.  And the area of mathematics involved.  Consult other papers where these are similar to yours, and see what it done there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to, but it doesn't hurt. Just keep the description short, making sure to include a term that enables someone who doesn't know what complex numbers are or natural numbers to look it up. "...where $\mathbb{C}$ is the field of complex numbers..." that's perfectly nice, short and sweet. Or $\textbf{C}$, for those who don't like blackboard bold.

As pointed out in the comments, there is some disagreement over whether $\mathbb{N}$ includes 0 or not. It's best to preempt that distraction by being perfectly clear on whether you intend to include it or not.

Comment: There is no disagreement: there are those like me that don't include 0 in N, and those that are wrong.

Comment: It it does hurt, though very mildly, in my opinion. When writing papers in math---indeed, when writing papers in anything---it's best to remove superfluous information. My general philosophy is that writing should be condensed as much possible, lest the reader finds it long-winded.

Comment: In response to your first comment, @Mariano, I wish I had that Facebook Haha emoticon.

Comment: @math, I don't know how much experience you have writing papers, but is sounds like you don't have a lot of experience *reading* them, as otherwise you'd be very aware of the many, incompatible conventions people use assuming they are universal, silently and to the only effect of general annoyance.

Comment: Mariano makes a good point. Like for example if I drop in a couple of $\delta_n^m$s without even saying they're Kronecker deltas.